# Multiple variables in for loop, kotlin

Tags: for-loop, variables, kotlin

Is it possible to make a for loop in kotlin with more than one variable? I'm looking for something simular to this:

```
for(x in 0..2, y in 3..6)
```

Is this possible in kotlin?

In java you could just do this:

```
for(x=0, y=3; x<=2 && y<= 6; x++, y++)
```

Comment: I dont want a nested for-loop, no

Comment: do you want something like: `for(x in 0..2) { for (y in 3..6) { } }`? or something like: `x=0, y=3` followed by `x=1, y=4`? If the latter: how should that behave if the indices do not match? (e.g. if (0..2).count() and (3..6).count() doesn't match)

Comment: @Roland posibly the OP wants  something like Java's `for(i=0,j=0;i<x && j<x;i++,j++)`

Comment: @forpas thanks for the hint... I never really required such a construct... and I would rather prefer nested loops to be honest... just copy/pasted that code into Intellij and got the following... "at least" it isn't nested anymore ;-) `val x = 10; var i = 0; var j = 0; while (i < x && j < x) { i++;j++; /* code */ }` (still... I wouldn't even use that one ;-))

Comment: @forpas Yes, thats exactly what im looking for, but in kotlin

Comment: @Kris10an just read at the link posted by others. This can't be done in Kotlin.

Comment: Yes, it can be done — see my comment to the linked question.  You can write `for ((x, y) in seqs(0..2, 3..6))` if you define a simple seqs() appropriately.